# Why does a written note sent through the mail have the same name as an individual letter?

Tags: etymology

A good question from a child: why does a written/printed message sent through the mail (a letter) have the same name as an individual symbol in the alphabet (a letter)?

Wiktionary's etymology doesn't clear this up:

> From Middle English letter, lettre, from Old French letre, from Latin littera (“letter of the alphabet"; in plural, "epistle”), from Etruscan, from Ancient Greek διφθέρᾱ (diphthérā, “tablet”).

Comment: Note the part of the etymology that says “in plural”: originally, the mailed letter was considered _letters_, i.e., a collection of individual letters, which makes sense. Somewhere along the way, this distinction was lost and the singular took over for both meanings.

Answer (score 1):

The Latin word "[littera](https://translate.google.com/#en/la/letter)" doesn't just mean "letter" but is also a word that means "literature," which means writings.  If this does not satisfy, teach your child the word "missive" and be done with it.

Answer (score 1):

It all started with Latin, where the term *littera* (from which letter via Old French *lectre*) mean both an althabetic letter and a a writing, a document.

> - c. 1200, "graphic symbol, alphabetic sign, written character conveying information about sound in speech," from Old French letre "character, letter; missive, note," in plural, "literature, writing, learning" (10c., Modern French lettre), ***from Latin littera (also litera) "letter of the alphabet," also "an epistle, writing, document***; literature, great books; science, learning;" a word of uncertain origin.

(Etymonline)

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that the envelope or the note in it or the paper on which the note is written is really **not** the "letter". The "letter" is what is written in the note or more precisely, the content of the note, some "letters" (alphabets). By generalization, we could call all of them a "letter", though.

Better do it before your kid asks about the house-owner.